# Subscript out of range when copying range to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, subscript

I am writing a reporting system where the user fills out a form and a form button runs a macro to save the file with a name based on several fields including a timestamp.

All the data is is also on a second sheet but in one row for ease of copying to a master sheet.

I am trying to to extend the save macro to copy this row to the last line of a second workbook.

This was successful when the macro was run from a separate workbook but I can't for the life of me work out how to do it from within the file itself.

I've triple checked the paths themselves, I know they're right as the new files are being created, I've run msgbox in the code to check the filename and the variable are the same too.

```
timestampedfile = Worksheets("single_line").Range("b3")
totalpath = Path & timestampedfile & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs filename:=totalpath
master_wb = "s:\blah\blah\blah.xlsx"  
master_sht = "Master_Database"
contact_wb = totalpath
contact_sht = "single_line"

Workbooks.Open (master_wb)
Workbooks.Open (contact_wb)

MsgBox (totalpath)

Workbooks(contact_wb).Worksheets(contact_sht).Range("A3:AQ3").Copy Worksheets(master_wb).Sheets(master_sht).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
```

'

Both the Workbooks open so I know the paths are right, can anyone help?

Comment: With that error it means the spelling of the sheet or workbook is wrong

Comment: Use workbook variables, instead of referencing the workbook by name: `Dim masterWb as Workbook`, then `Set masterWb = Workbooks.Open("s:\blah\blah\blah.xlsx" )`. Similarly for the contact workbook. You might consider using worksheet variables too, instead of using sheet names.

Comment: To test things like this add lines like, "s = masterWb.name", where s is defined earlier using "Dim s as string". Then you can hover over the variable after that line is executed to see if it's what you expect. Simple debugging, but it solves a lot of problems.

Comment: It's good that you edited your post and gave credit to @BigBen. However, the proper way to give credit to someone is to mark their comment/answer using the checkbox/up-arrow next to it. That way they get recognized and have more points/privileges on the forum.

Comment: It wasn't appearing, I think I have to have 15 trip to do that. I'll look again.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP*

Solved thanks to comment about workbook variables by BigBen:

> Use workbook variables, instead of referencing the workbook by name: `Dim masterWb as Workbook, then Set masterWb = Workbooks.Open("s:\blah\blah\blah.xlsx" )`. Similarly for the contact workbook. You might consider using worksheet variables too, instead of using sheet names.

Code changed to:

```
Dim master_wb As Workbook
Dim contact_wb As Workbook
Dim master_sht As Worksheet
Dim contact_sht As Worksheet

Path = "S:\blah\" & Worksheets("report").Range("c8") & "\"
filename = Worksheets("back_end_formulas").Range("e10")
timestampedfile = Worksheets("single_line").Range("b3")
totalpath = Path & timestampedfile & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs filename:=totalpath
SetAttr totalpath, vbReadOnly

Set master_wb = Workbooks.Open("S:\blah\Master_Database2.xlsx")
Set master_sht = master_wb.Sheets("Master_Database")
Set contact_wb = Workbooks.Open(totalpath)
Set contact_sht = contact_wb.Sheets("single_line")

ThisWorkbook.Activate

contact_sht.Range("A3:AQ3").Copy master_sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)

master_wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
contact_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```